# Passing a bash command to a remote host using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ssh

Doing a migration my bit of code is

```
cat /etc/fstab |grep nfs >/root/mounts.txt
cat /etc/fstab |grep cifs >> /root/mounts.txt
rsync -av /root/mounts.txt                              ${REMOTEHOST}:/root/
ssh root@${REMOTEHOST} 'cat /root/mounts.txt >> /etc/fstab'
ssh root@${REMOTEHOST} 'for i in $(cat /root/mounts.txt |awk '{print $2}');do mkdir -p $i; done'
```

Problem is that the last line works locally:

```
 for i in $(cat /root/mounts.txt |awk '{print $2}');do mkdir -p $i; done
```

However when I am passing it to the remote host I am getting:

> " {print
>
> awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string"

Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Your "inner" single quotes are not "inner" at all. They are ending (and restarting) the outer single quoted string. You need to escape them. Replace them with `'\''` (single-quote backslash single-quote single-quote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the command provided in the `ssh` gets stopped when writing the first quote of the `awk` expression.

So you may want to use another approach:

```
ssh root@${REMOTEHOST} 'while read -r _ host _; do mkdir -p $host; done < /root/mounts.txt'
```

This uses a `while read variable1 variable2 variable3` so that you don't need to use `awk` to get the second value.

Comment: Yes that's better approach +1